# MathTimePro right angle bracket spacing

Tags: spacing, times

I am using the MathTimePro math font and noticed that the spacing
for the right angle bracket is too tight when it is used in the `\LEFTRIGHT<>{...}` macro. Here is a MWE:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
Spacing on the right angle bracket is incorrect
in the \texttt{LEFTRIGHT<>} macro:
\begin{equation}
\langle S \rangle \quad \text{versus} \quad
\LEFTRIGHT<>{S}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\left\langle
\sum a_k x_k,
\sum b_j x_j
 \right\rangle \quad \text{versus} \quad
\LEFTRIGHT<>{
\sum a_k x_k,
\sum b_j x_j
}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\left< \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4} \right>
\quad\text{versus}\quad
\LEFTRIGHT<>{\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}}
\end{equation}

\vskip15pt
Some extra space \verb|\,| is needed:
\begin{equation}
\langle S \rangle \quad \text{versus} \quad
\LEFTRIGHT<>{S\,}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\left\langle
\sum a_k x_k,
\sum b_j x_j
 \right\rangle \quad \text{versus} \quad
\LEFTRIGHT<>{
\sum a_k x_k,
\sum b_j x_j\,
}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\left< \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4} \right>
\quad\text{versus}\quad
\LEFTRIGHT<>{\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}\,}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Am I doing something incorrectly and is there a way to fix this behavior? Thanks!

Comment: This does seem to be a bug: there is an explicit `\mskip-\thinmuskip` in the definition of `\LEFTRIGHT` that causes it. This is not the only problem: the content of the macro can be shifted vertically from where it should be placed (look carefully at the relative height and depth of the two `S`s). I think I would never use this macro.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Unfortunately, this macro is the only documented way to use the 'extra large' delimiters provided by the MathTime Pro package :O